# Check if a file exists in UNIX from SQLplus without UTL_FILE

Tags: database, unix, oracle11g, sqlplus

My current scenario is like this:

- I need to **login to sqlplus** from a **shell script** to call a **stored procedure**.
- After that I need to create a **CSV** file by SPOOLING data from a table.
- Then I need to **check whether the CSV file has been created** in a particular directory and depending on the result an **update** query needs to be run.

I know that this can be checked within sqlplus with the help of **UTL_FILE** package but unfortunately due to Client policies,the access of this package is **restricted** in  the current system.

Another way is to exit from sqlplus and perform the file check in UNIX and then again log in to sqlplus to perform the rest actions. But this I believe would result in **slower execution time** and **performance** is an important factor in this implementation as the tables contain huge volumes of data(**in millions**).

So is there any other way to check this from sqlplus without exiting from the current session?

**System Info:**

**OS - Red Hat Enterprise Linux**

**Database - Oracle 11g**

Comment: Is the file identified by the procedure - otherwise why can't you check for it before you first log in to SQL\*Plus? Also is the file on the client or server machine, if they are different?

Comment: @AlexPoole: I missed that part. Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the question. The file is being created in the Client machine.

Comment: OK. If the server is a different machine, `utl_file` wouldn't work anyway; that only operates on the server filesystem, while spool (and host) only operate on the client.

Comment: Incidentally, why would exiting and relaunching SQL\*Plus be a problem - doing that once won't take long? It would commit any changes made so far, of course, which you might not want. The size of the tables doesn't seem relevant though.

Comment: Yes, commiting would cause a problem. And also there is a large exception handling part which would have to be written twice if the connection were made twice. That would result in redundant code. So the other developers of the team are against it.

Comment: Hmmm.... that makes it sound like you're trying to do the spool and file file check from inside a PL/SQL block. You can't do that; spool is an SQL\*Plus command - you could start spooling before the block, so it captures `dbms_output` calls for instance, but you can't start spooling from inside the block. And you can't interact with the user or the client machine either. The PL/SQL executes inside the Oracle instance on the server, so it can't see the client filesystem, or the spool file. Maybe more explanation would help; can you add a cut-down example of what you're doing as code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is on the same machine that you're running SQL*Plus on, you could potentially use [the `host` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve026.htm#SQPUG047).

If the file you're checking is the same one you're spooling to, it must exist anyway, or you would have got an SP error of some kind; but if you do want to check the same file for some reason, and assuming you have a substitution variable with the file name:

```
define csv_file=/path/to/spool.csv
-- call procedure
spool &csv_file
-- do query
spool off

host ls &csv_file

update your_table
set foo=bar
where &_rc = 0;
```

If the file exists when the `host` command is run, the `_rc` substitution variable will be set to zero. If the file doesn't exist or isn't readable for any reason it will be something else - e.g. 2 if the file just doesn't exist. Adding the check `&_rc = 0` to your update will mean no rows are updated if there was an error. (You can of course still have whatever other conditions you need for the update).

You could suppress the display of the file name by adding `1>/dev/null` to the host command string; and could also suppress any error messages by also adding `2>/dev/null`, though you might want to see those.

The documentation warns against using `&_rc` as it isn't portable; but it works on RHEL so as long as you don't need your script to be portable to other operating systems this may be good enough for you. What you can't do, though, is do anything with the contents of the file, or interpret anything about it. All you have available is the return code from the command you run. If you need anything more sophisticated you could call a script that generates specific return codes, but that's getting a bit messy.

Comment: Wonderful!! This works... but it would be great if this can be done in an OS independent way. Can the output be assigned to a variable and checked from SQLPlus itself?

Comment: The output of the host command can't be seen by SQL\*Plus, no. If you were on the DB server, and were allowed to use `utl_file`, you could redirect the output to a file and then read it from PL/SQL - but that option isn't available to you. Or your host command could be a script that inserts something into the DB, but that's getting even messier. I'm not sure which OSes support `&_rc`; never tried it on Windows, for instance.